# Triangle with two slopes and x-axis

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Triangle has:

Side 1 (p): `x-2y+1=0`

Side 2 (q): `x+y-2=0`

Side 3: x-axis

What is the area of this triangle?

I know that it has 2 equal sides but I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried ? How do you compute the area of a triangle ?

Comment: I tried to find the interception of the scopes by solving a system and it was (1, 1), I also tried to get the tgα of each scope, they were 1/2 and 1. For the area I think I should use [this](https://ibb.co/37tPT82)?

Comment: So you know $\left(1;1\right)$ is one of the three points. Find the two others first and use the cross product as you suggested

Comment: That was my original plan but I don't know how to find the other points. I know they look like this A(xa, 0) and B(xb, 0).

Comment: You are absolutely right, but you know that one of your point is on $(p)$ and the other on $(q)$.

Comment: I'm voting to close because you should have included your work in the body of the Question, not only in the Comments.  If you remedy this, I'll happily vote to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the area of the triangle. First find the two vertices on $x$-axis by substituting $y=0$ into (p) and (q), and you'll get $(-1,0),(2,0)$, the length of the side along the $x$-axis is $3$.

Now solve (p) and (q) to get the third vertex $(1,1)$. So the height corresponding to the side above is $|1|=1$.

Therefore the area is $A=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 3\cdot 1=\frac{3}{2}$.